# Javascript get id from a randomized id

Tags: javascript, php

Hello i want to get the id using this code, (chart-0 to be replaced by the id)

`var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart-0');`

from this element

`<div id="<?=$graph_id?>" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></div>`

im using php to increment the value

```
<?php

        $g = 0;
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

        $graph_id = 'chart-' .$g;
         $g++;
  ?>
```

Using a div element, im retrieving the id with `data-target="#<?=$current_id?>` and it work fine, but how to do it with javascript `get.documentByID`?
This one `data-target="#<?=$current_id?>` is another example, how to target the `<?=$graph_id?>` using `get.documentByID`

Thank you in advance

Comment: are u using jquery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem:
The php code generates ids on the server. The client doesn't know which number the php started at or how many there are.

Possible solutions:

- Echo each id on the php, which means you have to handcode each id into the code already, since you cant loop php code in js.
- Have the php write the ids in an array variable in the javascript so you can loop over them.
- Assume the id always starts at 0 so you can getElementById in a loop.

Better solution:

Use code that doesn't rely on knowing the id and parse it dynamically or just use a class name instead. Both results in the same thing though, only the selector differs.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="chart-0" class="ns-chart" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></div>
    <div id="chart-12" class="ns-chart" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></div>
    <div id="chart-57" class="ns-chart" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></div>
<script>
var chartsById = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="chart-"]'),
    data = [], // your data
    options = {}; // your options
Array.prototype.slice.call(chartsById).forEach(function( chartDiv, index ) {
    // We don't actually need the id or idnumber here, sicne we just have to use the html element to create the chart.
    // var id = chart.id;
    // var idNumber = chart.id.slice(6);
    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart( chartDiv );
    chart.draw( data, options );
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The advantages here are:

- It doesn't matter how many charts you have.
- Or at which number the ids start.
- Or if there's gaps in the ids.
- Seperation of javascript and php code.

PHP Only version: These PHP snippets ar examples only, this isn't good code. The code may also not work 100% as I'm not a php programmer. Just trying to show the differences and issues.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
    $g = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $graph_id = 'chart-' .$g;
        echo '<div id="'.$graph_id.'" class="ns-chart" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></div>';
        echo '<script>var chart-'.$g.' = document.getElementById("'.$graph_id.'");</script>'
        $g++;
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Different version, less bad, but equally annoying to work with.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
    $g = 0;
    $ids = '[';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $graph_id = 'chart-' .$g;
        echo '<div id="'.$graph_id.'" class="ns-chart" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></div>';
        $ids.'"'.$graph_id.'",'
        $g++;
    }
    $ids.'];'
    echo '<script>var idAry = '.$ids.';</script>';
?>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have 20 possibility of charts and each may be repeated more than once..so you are telling me to define 20 different divs?

Comment: Ofcourse not, the php creates those divs. You asked for an example in the comments, so I included some example divs. You ONLY would have to write all 20 of those divs seperately if you want to use `echo document.getElementById("<?=$graph_id?>")` in the PHP loop. Hence we're suggesting to not do that and just use the JS selectors.

Comment: I've added a 'bad' php only example. The disadvantages here include: all vars are global, no option to extract the JS into a seperate file or module, no seperation of concerns etc.

Comment: Im going for your best solution while im reading on the other side about selectors. But something, the variable `idAry` and `idNumber` contains something? since `idAry` is not assigned to something and variable `id` and `chart.id` is empty too if im not mistaken

Comment: idAry can be removed. I was first thinking of putting all the ids into an array, but then decided justshowing the loop would be more clear. Inside the loop function, I used the vars id and idNumber to save things you'll need in the loop. id is not empty, since chart.id returns the id of that element, the var id will contain the string "chart-x", with x being the number. Then idNumber contains the string with only the number, after slicing off the "chart-" part. You could inline them like `console.log("The chart at index " +  index + " has the id " + chart.id.slice(6));` and not use the var.

Comment: But since the loop will contain more stuff than only a console.log, you'll probably need those ids and numbers more than once. Then it's better to just save it in an id. Eg: `console.log('the id is: ' + chart.id.slice(6));var nextId = parseInt( chart.id.slice(6) ) + 1, previousId = parseInt( chart.id.slice(6) ) - 1;` is worse than `var id = chart.id.slice(6);console.log('the id is: ' + id);var nextId = parseInt( id ) + 1, previousId = parseInt( id ) - 1;`, since in the first one, you do the same id calculation trice instead of one calculation and one assignment to a var. Dont repeat yourself.

Comment: It works, saw them on f12> console, now how do i link it so that the chart can be displayed?

`var chart = new` `google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('idNumber'));`?

bare with me, im a beginner and not an english talker thank you

Comment: No idea, your code doesn't include the rendering part of the charts. I'm assuming that that google library will have something like `chart.render( chartDiv );` or `chartDiv.append( chart )` Look for the syntax in the docs of the google AreaChart.

Comment: It does, because when i hard code it, it does work, this is the code:
`var chart = new` `google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('idNumber'));`
      `chart.draw(data, options);`

values of data and options are already set

Comment: I have updated the code I posted. Basically, instead of getting the id from the div and logging it, we just use the div element to create the chart and draw it directly. So replace data wih your data and options with your options and draw. :) Hope it works.

Comment: I works! Thank you :) not i got some issue i must review with my php, displaying only 1 graph :( thanks!

Comment: Same for you! God bless you :)

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById` is used with ID known beforehand.

In your case, you can use instead `document.querySelector` to match the first element or `document.querySelectorAll` to match all elements .

Indeed, `document.querySelector` accepts CSS selectors :

```
document.querySelector('[id^="chart-"]')
```

means element has id starts with `chart-`

---

and to parse ID Just remove the prefix "chart-" and call `parseInt` if needed :

```
   const prefix = "chart-";
   const parseId= (fullId) => parseInt( fullId.slice(prefix.length) );
   parseId(
     document.querySelector('[id^="chart-"]').id
   );
```

```js
  const parseId= (fullId) => fullId.slice("chart-".length);
   parseId(
     document.querySelector('[id^="chart-"]').id
 );
console.log(
      document.querySelectorAll('[id^="chart-"]')
.length, 
  ' elements has ID starts with "chart-"'
)

console.log('Random ID is ',
   parseId(document.querySelector('[id^=chart-]').id)  
 )
```

```html
<div id="chart-1231"></div>

<div id="ch-232"></div>
```

Comment: Once you have the element, you can parse the id into a number. And you can replace `$()` with `document.querySelectorAll()` if you don't use JQuery.

Comment: since im using php doesnt i need something like <?php echo$graph_id?>

which will take the id chart-0 for example and put it in the document.getelementByID? 
your answer is a bit too diffcult for me to understand :/

Comment: Javascript and Php, the javascript is to display a graph for the given div id=

Comment: Ok .. and thank for @Shilly.. because i thought the question is tagged jquery .. `querySelector` gives your the first element that meets the selection .. and `querySelectorAll` gives u ALL elements that meets the selection

Comment: all this code to get the id? if i want to use only 1 incremental value, lets stay im not using chart-0, im just using 0, 1, 2 using the $g, how to retrieve the id in this case, because this is really complex, im still an university student

Comment: @YoanDeChaton—sounds like you should be using a class so you can get all the elements with a particular class, then loop over them and do whatever you like with whatever attributes you're interested in.

Comment: Well, two questions, get element and then parse ID are going to take at least 2 lines of code. And this isn't complex, this is basics.

Comment: @RobG:  good suggestion . Shilly : thank you  for your follow-up

Comment: Can you please give me an example? I mean, i thought there was some way just to use the echo $graph_id in the get.documentElementByID, i feel so stupid :/